# JavaScript OnBlur event prevents HTML form from being submitted

Tags: javascript, forms, dom-events, form-submit, onblur

Consider the following form:

```
<form action="/a" method="post"> 
    <input name="x" type="text" onblur="myonblur(e)" />
    <input name="y" type="text" />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

When focus is on element with name "x" and user presses submit button, `onblur` event fires but form is NOT submitted. Is there any way to make submit button work as expected if I have `onblur` events in my form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider optimizing your `onBlur()` method so it takes less time to run. If your form is prevented from getting submitted, it might be because the `onBlur()` is too long and hangs the browser from doing anything else.

You can also use the `onChange()` method instead of  `onBlur()`. That may work better for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Idea is to check is username exists via AJAX call, so with onChange() it would be much harder to implement, if possible. So, you mean, there is no way for me to use onBlur()?

Comment: You should use asynchronous AJAX requests which run in the background and don't hang the browser. By using those the onSubmit will still work even if the ajax request isn't finished. Jquery library does async by default, have a look at http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax

Answer (score -1):

Try adding

```
return true;
```

after calling your onBlur function. The problem you are facing with might be due to "return false" prevention of the event handlers.

Comment: No. The first answer was correct. I tried your approach and it did not help.

Comment: OK. It was just a possibility though ;)